# texttable draw changes the format of the content

Tags: python

I'm trying to draw a table with texttable. I have this piece of code to arrange the content of the table:

```
def get_int_avg_pre(r_list, p_list):
li = []
recall_list = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
for recall in recall_list:
    r_ind = 0
    for i in r_list:
        if float(i)/100 >= recall:
            r_ind = r_list.index(i)
            break
    pre = max(p_list[r_ind:])
    li.append([str(recall), "{:.2f}".format(float(pre)/100)])
return li


def print_logs(qs, rs):
    t = Texttable()
    inter_val = get_int_avg_pre(r_list, p_list)

    printed_list = [['Recall', 'Interpolated Precision']]

    for el in inter_val:
        printed_list.append(el)

    t.add_rows(printed_list)

    print t.draw()
```

I skipped some parts as you see, since they are irrelevant to my question. With this script, the table content is not what I want in terms of formatting. Outputs are below and I can to see the exact values in the printed_list. Can someone help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

printed_list:

```
[['Recall', 'Interpolated Precision'], ['0.0', '1.00'], ['0.1', '1.00'], ['0.2', '1.00'], ['0.3', '0.50'], ['0.4', '0.50'], ['0.5', '0.50'], ['0.6', '0.38'], ['0.7', '0.38'], ['0.8', '0.36'], ['0.9', '0.36'], ['1.0', '0.36']]
```

Table:

[image: Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that if no type specified for the values of columns, **auto** type is assigned to it. It means most possible type will be evaluated. Since **1.0** or **0.0** is closer the integer than float, they were converted to int. For the rest, they were closer to float and converted accordingly with a default precision 3.

The solution in my case was to use

```
t.set_cols_dtype(["t", "t"])
```

just before the line

```
tt.add_rows(printed_list)
```

to give the specific field types. I used **text** as in my case I already formatted my input however, texttable supports **float** with a configurable precision as field type hence using it was also probable.